# How to get summed up values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my current Query:

```
 SELECT dbo.TOL.sName AS sMacName, dbo.JOB.sName AS sJobName,
        dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtBegin AS tShiftBegin, dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtEnd AS tShiftEnd,
        SUM(dbo.SHT_SUM.dActShots) AS dShots, '450' AS dQuant,
        SUM(dbo.SHT_SUM.dActScrap) AS dScrap, MAX(dbo.JOB.iSetCavity) as SetCavity,
        CASE
            WHEN (dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR.iScrap) LIKE '99' THEN (dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR.dActScrap)
            ELSE '0'
        END as TOS
   FROM dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SHT_SUM ON dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR.lShtSumRef = dbo.SHT_SUM.lShtSumRef
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JOB ON dbo.SHT_SUM.lJobRef = dbo.JOB.lJobRef
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TOL ON dbo.SHT_SUM.lMacRef = dbo.TOL.lTolRef
  WHERE dbo.TOL.bInactive = 0
    AND dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtDay > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    AND GETDATE() BETWEEN dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtBegin AND dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtEnd
    AND iSetCavity is Not NUll
  GROUP BY dbo.TOL.sName, dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtBegin, dbo.SHT_SUM.tShtEnd, dbo.JOB.sName,
        dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR.iScrap, dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR.dActScrap
  ORDER BY sMacName
```

and it currently returns:

```
sMacName    sJobName    tShiftBegin             tShiftEnd               dShots  dQuant  dScrap  SetCavity   TOS
FT2-E14     10401445710 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 98      450     2       2           0
FT2-E14     10401445710 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 98      450     2       2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           6
```

but I want it to return:

```
FT2-E14     IGNORE      2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 223     450     12      2           6
```

So to sum it up:

1. Group By sMacName
2. Dont care about the JobName (dont need it in the result)
3. Group by tShiftBegin
4. Group by tShiftEnd
5. Sum of dShots where sJobName is the same
6. Group by dQuant
7. Sum of dScrap where sJobName is the same
8. Group by SetCavity
9. Sum of TOS

Is this somehow possible with SQL?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 5. sum of dShots where sJobName is the same, if you say 2. dont care about JobName?

Comment: I meant, that I dont need it in the result, but it is needed to make the sum.

Comment: Ahh, i see. didn't read the question properly, I'm sorry - Writing an answer atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the most efficient solution, but it does do the trick.

Starting by your original query (edited a bit for readability):

```
SELECT     
  t.sName            AS sMacName
, j.sName            AS sJobName
, ss.tShtBegin       AS tShiftBegin
, ss.tShtEnd         AS tShiftEnd
, SUM(ss.dActShots)  AS dShots
, '450'              AS dQuant
, SUM(ss.dActScrap)  AS dScrap
, MAX(j.iSetCavity)  as SetCavity
, CASE
   WHEN (scr.iScrap) LIKE '99' THEN (scr.dActScrap)
   ELSE '0'
END                  as TOS
FROM dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR scr
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SHT_SUM ss  ON scr.lShtSumRef = ss.lShtSumRef 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JOB j        ON ss.lJobRef = j.lJobRef 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TOL t       ON ss.lMacRef = t.lTolRef
WHERE 1=1
and t.bInactive = 0
AND (ss.tShtDay > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) 
AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN ss.tShtBegin AND ss.tShtEnd) 
AND (j.iSetCavity is Not NUll)
GROUP BY 
   t.sName
, ss.tShtBegin
, ss.tShtEnd
, j.sName
, scr.iScrap
, scr.dActScrap
--ORDER BY sMacName
```

which returns

```
sMacName    sJobName    tShiftBegin             tShiftEnd               dShots  dQuant  dScrap  SetCavity   TOS
FT2-E14     10401445710 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 98      450     2       2           0
FT2-E14     10401445710 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 98      450     2       2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           0
FT2-E14     10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125     450     10      2           6
```

I put this query in a subquery, so that i group by sJobName:

```
select 
  i.sMacName    
, i.sJobName   
, i.tShiftBegin
, i.tShiftEnd
, max(i.dShots ) as dShots 
, i.dQuant
, max(i.dScrap ) as dScrap
, i.SetCavity
, sum(i.TOS ) as TOS
from (
   SELECT     
     t.sName            AS sMacName
   , j.sName            AS sJobName
   , ss.tShtBegin       AS tShiftBegin
   , ss.tShtEnd         AS tShiftEnd
   , SUM(ss.dActShots)  AS dShots
   , '450'              AS dQuant
   , SUM(ss.dActScrap)  AS dScrap
   , MAX(j.iSetCavity)  as SetCavity
   , CASE
      WHEN (scr.iScrap) LIKE '99' THEN (scr.dActScrap)
      ELSE '0'
   END                  as TOS
   FROM dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR scr
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SHT_SUM ss  ON scr.lShtSumRef = ss.lShtSumRef 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JOB j        ON ss.lJobRef = j.lJobRef 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TOL t       ON ss.lMacRef = t.lTolRef
   WHERE 1=1
   and t.bInactive = 0
   AND (ss.tShtDay > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) 
   AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN ss.tShtBegin AND ss.tShtEnd) 
   AND (j.iSetCavity is Not NUll)
   GROUP BY 
      t.sName
   , ss.tShtBegin
   , ss.tShtEnd
   , j.sName
   , scr.iScrap
   , scr.dActScrap
   --ORDER BY sMacName
) i
group by 
  i.sMacName    
, i.sJobName   
, i.tShiftBegin
, i.tShiftEnd
--, i.dShots 
, i.dQuant 
--, i.dScrap 
, i.SetCavity  
--, i.TOS
```

which returns:

```
sMacName    sJobName    tShiftBegin tShiftEnd   dShots  dQuant  dScrap  SetCavity   TOS
FT2-E14 10401445710 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 98  450 2   2   0
FT2-E14 10401445792 2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 125 450 10  2   6
```

This can then once again be put in a subquery, to do the final group by:

```
select 
  i2.sMacName
, 'IGNORE' as sJobName
, i2.tShiftBegin
, i2.tShiftEnd
, sum(i2.dShots)
, i2.dQuant
, sum(i2.dScrap)
, i2.SetCavity
, sum(i2.TOS)
from (
   select 
     i.sMacName    
   , i.sJobName   
   , i.tShiftBegin
   , i.tShiftEnd
   , max(i.dShots ) as dShots 
   , i.dQuant
   , max(i.dScrap ) as dScrap
   , i.SetCavity
   , sum(i.TOS ) as TOS
   from (
      SELECT     
        t.sName            AS sMacName
      , j.sName            AS sJobName
      , ss.tShtBegin       AS tShiftBegin
      , ss.tShtEnd         AS tShiftEnd
      , SUM(ss.dActShots)  AS dShots
      , '450'              AS dQuant
      , SUM(ss.dActScrap)  AS dScrap
      , MAX(j.iSetCavity)  as SetCavity
      , CASE
         WHEN (scr.iScrap) LIKE '99' THEN (scr.dActScrap)
         ELSE '0'
      END                  as TOS
      FROM dbo.SHT_SUM_SCR scr
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SHT_SUM ss  ON scr.lShtSumRef = ss.lShtSumRef 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JOB j        ON ss.lJobRef = j.lJobRef 
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TOL t       ON ss.lMacRef = t.lTolRef
      WHERE 1=1
      and t.bInactive = 0
      AND (ss.tShtDay > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) 
      AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN ss.tShtBegin AND ss.tShtEnd) 
      AND (j.iSetCavity is Not NUll)
      GROUP BY 
         t.sName
      , ss.tShtBegin
      , ss.tShtEnd
      , j.sName
      , scr.iScrap
      , scr.dActScrap
      --ORDER BY sMacName
   ) i
   group by 
     i.sMacName    
   , i.sJobName   
   , i.tShiftBegin
   , i.tShiftEnd
   --, i.dShots 
   , i.dQuant 
   --, i.dScrap 
   , i.SetCavity  
   --, i.TOS 
) i2
group by 
  i2.sMacName
, i2.tShiftBegin
, i2.tShiftEnd
, i2.dQuant
, i2.SetCavity
```

This sure as heck aint pretty, but it does return this:

```
sMacName    sJobName    tShiftBegin tShiftEnd   (No column name)    dQuant  (No column name)    SetCavity   (No column name)
FT2-E14 IGNORE  2014-05-13 05:00:00.000 2014-05-13 13:00:00.000 223 450 12  2   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working Fiddle using a subquery to do the first round of grouping: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f819/10)

**SQL Table Creation (simply for reference from the fiddle):**

```
create table SHT_SUM_SCR  (
  sMacName nvarchar(100),
  sJobName nvarchar(100),
  tShiftBegin datetime,
  tShiftEnd datetime,
  dShots int,
  dQuant int,
  dScrap int,
  SetCavity int,
  TOS int
  )

insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445710','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',98,450,2,2,0)
insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445710','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',98,450,2,2,0)
insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445792','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',125,450,10,2,0)
insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445792','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',125,450,10,2,0)
insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445792','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',125,450,10,2,0)
insert into SHT_SUM_SCR(sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,TOS)
values('FT2-E14','10401445792','2014-05-13 05:00:00.000','2014-05-13 13:00:00.000',125,450,10,2,6)
```

**Query to get results:**

```
select sMacName,
      tShiftBegin,
      tShiftEnd,
      sum(dShots) as dshots,
      dQuant,
      sum(dScrap) as dScrap,
      SetCavity,
      sum(TOS) as TOS
from
(
  -- subquery - place your query here
  select sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,
        dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity,sum(TOS) as tos
  from SHT_SUM_SCR
  group by sMacName,sJobName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dShots,dQuant,dScrap,SetCavity
  -- subquery end
) as results
group by sMacName,tShiftBegin,tShiftEnd,dQuant,SetCavity
```

If you modify this query and wrap the outer SQL around your query you should get the same results.